# React functional component execute multiple times, with useSelector() is executed multiple times in each function component execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've read through documents about hooks but don't see enough detailed information about the lifecycle of components when working with hooks, hence I need your help.

To be more specific, I have a sample code with the following related questions: https://github.com/khoitnm/practice-react-redux/tree/main/pro-00-old-react-version/src/comp-04-clickButton

**Question 1)** My functional component uses 3 hooks: `useSelector`, `useDispatch`, `useEffect`, but then why the component is executed 4 times (detail in the code and screenshot below)?
From my understanding, it should be only 3 times:

1. Initiation
2. The `useSelector` triggers this execution
3. The `useEffect` triggers this execution. The `useDispatch` will not trigger any additional execution, then why the data show 4 times?

Below are my code and screenshot.
The component:

```
let componentCount = 0;
let returnCount = 0;
let useSelectorCount = 0;
let useEffectCount = 0;

const Comp04ClickButtonPage = (): JSX.Element => {
    componentCount++;
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - START ----------------------`);

    // useSelector
    const stringValueState = useSelector((rootState: RootState): string => {
        useSelectorCount++;
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] selectorCount: ${useSelectorCount}`);
        const result = rootState.comp04ClickButtonSlice.stringValue;
        return result;
    });
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - after useSelectorCount`);

    // useEffect
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        useEffectCount++;
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] effectCount: ${useEffectCount}.`);
        dispatch(thunkComp04ClickButton(`${new Date().getTime()}`));
    }, [dispatch]);
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - after useEffect`);

    const onClickButton = () => {
        componentCount = returnCount = useSelectorCount = useEffectCount = 0; // reset counts
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] onClickNewValue`);
        dispatch(thunkComp04ClickButton(`Random ${new Date().getTime()}`));
    };

    // render
    returnCount++;
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(`[${componentCount}] renderCount: ${returnCount}`)}
            <div>
                [{componentCount}], useEffect: {useEffectCount}, useSelectorCount: {useSelectorCount}, returnCount: {returnCount}
            </div>
            <button onClick={onClickButton}>Click Button</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The thunk:

```
export const thunkComp04ClickButton = (stringValue: string): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        console.log(`AppThunk: saveStringValue "${stringValue}" start dispatch`);
        dispatch(setComp04ClickButtonState({ stringValue: stringValue }));
        console.log(`AppThunk: saveStringValue "${stringValue}" end dispatch`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`AppThunk: saveStringValue error dispatch` + err, err);
    }
};
```

The slice:

```
type Comp04ClickButtonState = {
    stringValue: string;
};

const initialState: Comp04ClickButtonState = {
    stringValue: 'Init Comp04ClickButtonState',
};

const comp04ClickButtonSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'comp04ClickButtonSlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setComp04ClickButtonState(state, action: PayloadAction<Comp04ClickButtonState>) {
            console.log(`Slice: setComp04ClickButtonState "${action.payload.stringValue}"`);
            return action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setComp04ClickButtonState } = comp04ClickButtonSlice.actions;
export default comp04ClickButtonSlice.reducer;
```

In the [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLBIa.png): you'll see that the componentCount is `[4]` and `returnCount: 4`

**Question 2)** When the component is triggered, why the `useSelector` is executed multiple times?

In more detail, we can see in the console log:
In the second execution of the component, the selectorCount increase from 2 to 5 times (totally 4 times)

```
[2] selectorCount: 2
[2] component - after useSelectorCount
[2] component - after useEffect
[2] renderCount: 2
[2] selectorCount: 3
[2] effectCount: 1.
AppThunk: saveStringValue "1610983429863" start dispatch
Slice: setComp04ClickButtonState "1610983429863"
[2] selectorCount: 4
AppThunk: saveStringValue "1610983429863" end dispatch
[2] selectorCount: 5
```

In summary, when I open that web page, the final result is:

- useEffect: 1 (as expected)
- componentCount = returnCount: 4 (many times)
- useSelector: 7 (why so many times???)

---

**UPDATED**: As @lawrence-witt mentioned, the `<React.StrictMode>` causes double-invokes on various things, so I change my `index.tsx` to use `<React.Fragment>` like this:

```
const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        </React.Fragment>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
};
```

As the result, the component now is executed only 2 times. However, as you see in the [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PndgJ.png), the console log still shows that the `useSelector` is triggered 4 times when the component is executed the first time. Hence the question 2 still remains: *Why is it triggered so many times?*

```
[1] component - START ----------------------
[1] selectorCount: 1
[1] component - after useSelectorCount
[1] component - after useEffect
[1] renderCount: 1
[1] selectorCount: 2
[1] effectCount: 1.
AppThunk: saveStringValue "1611023432655" start dispatch
Slice: setComp04ClickButtonState "1611023432655"
[1] selectorCount: 3
AppThunk: saveStringValue "1611023432655" end dispatch
[1] selectorCount: 4
```

Comment: Your `index.tsx` file has [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled. Make sure you remove it or create a build before testing stuff like this because it double-invokes various things like function component bodies and certain hooks. Apparently some console logs caused by the second invocation are now suppressed in React 17 but regardless you appear to be on 16.8.6.

Comment: Thank you @lawrence-witt, your comments help to understand a lot more.
I updated [my code](https://github.com/khoitnm/practice-react-redux/blob/main/pro-01-redux-simple/src/index.tsx) to remove StrictMode and use React 17. The component's total execution is reduced, but the `useSelector` is still triggered multiple times (I updated the question with more information at the end). Do you know why?

Comment: same issue happening to me

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when the `useSelector` hook is used, it updates the component every time the Redux-managed value changes. You can read more about `useSelector` here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector.

The dependency you added to `useEffect` can be removed as `dispatch` never changes. The official documentation for `useDispatch` can be found here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch.

```js
// This will be called only once when the component is mounted for the first time
useEffect(() => {
   initDispatch();
},[]);
const initDispatch = useCallback(()=>{
  useEffectCount++;
  console.log(`[${componentCount}] effectCount: ${useEffectCount}.`);
  dispatch(thunkComp04ClickButton(`${new Date().getTime()}`));
}, [dispatch]);
```

This code will still re-render the component when `dispatch` is called (because `dispatch` is in the `useCallback` dependency array) which will force `useSelector` to re-render the component.

Comment: Thank you @darshan-jain, 

The thing is, based on [that document]( https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector), I still can't explain the following things we see in the log (screenshot 2): First, the `useSelector` is executed 2 times (`selectorCount: 2`) before `useEffect` is triggered (`effectCount: 1`). Why's that?
And second, after the `dispatch`, the message `Slice: setComp04ClickButtonState "1611023432655"` is printed, and the `selectorCount` jumps to `3`, which makes sense. But then, why does it jump again to `4` after that?